# Add javascript file if the user is logged in

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How to add a javascript file or javascript code if the user is logged in to the website?

The website is built with drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
global $user;
if($user->uid != 0)
{
    drupal_add_js("PATH_TO_JS_FILE");
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: @OP: If you are wondering how to get this code working in your site, the easiest way (at least for me) is to create a tiny module that has hook_init. 

function mymodule_init(){
ABOVE CODE HERE
}